# Error while reading character using gets function

Tags: c, cc

I am writing a string to a file. But only the first part of the string is only inserted to file. Others are missing. For eg: If I write "I Like Flowers", "I" is only written into file.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char string[50];
        int marks,i,n;
        FILE *fptr; fptr=(fopen("string.txt","w"));
        if(fptr==NULL){
                printf("Error!");
                return 0;
        }
        printf("Enter a string : \n");
        scanf("%s", string);
        //fprintf(fptr,"%s",string);
        fwrite(string, 1, sizeof(string), fptr);

        fclose(fptr);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fwrite()` works fine

Comment: why this is downvoted? It would be helpful, if you can specify a reason before Downvoting.

Comment: Programmer should never assume problem with standard library, the problem always with the code you wrote. Well, there is a small, nearly non-existent chance to hit the stdlib bug, but you have to be 500% sure it is not your fault before assuming this.

Comment: Sorry. Actually I wrote the question about the bug in my program. Will change the title soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) will stop reading at the first space: that is the problem. The `scanf("%s")` only reads the `I` from standard input. To read the entire line use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. Use `strlen()` to write only what was read instead of using `sizeof(string)`.

Comment: Thanks. But after adding fgets the program is just exiting before I enter any string. Is this the correct syntax?  printf("Enter a string : \n");  fgets(string, 100, fptr);

Comment: `fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);`: note `stdin`. _Always_ check return values to ensure success of a function.

Comment: Again error. Segmentation fault: 11. Now the program is like this :     fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin); fwrite(string, sizeof(string), strlen(string), fptr); fclose(fptr);

Comment: Read [`fwrite()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite). I meant `strlen()` _instead of_ `sizeof()`.

Comment: You don't want to use `sizeof(string)` *and* `strlen(string)`, use `fwrite(string, 1, strlen(string), fptr);` instead. Otherwise you try to write (and thus read from `string`) `sizeof(string)` * `strlen(string)` characters, which is more than is allocated there.

Comment: "The scanf() will stop reading at the first space" mis-leads a bit. `scanf("%s")` scans (and does not save white space), then scans and saves non-white space, then "stop reading at the first space".

Answer (score 1):

In your code `scanf("%s",string)` only takes the string up to the first space. To read the total string "I Like Flowers", you have to use the `scanf` function like this:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s,string);
```

it will work.